# Why a:hover is not working with bootstrap source?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I included bootstrap in my website and then created a link, now first of all I started with a:link and a:visited and everything worked but then I started with a:hover and a:active and it didn't work at all ??

```
a:hover,a:active {
   text-decoration:none;
   color:grey;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't override css without being more specific like:

```
div a:hover,div a:active {
   text-decoration:none;
   color:grey;
}
```

Or if you want to override for all `a` tags (without being more specific element), you can add `!important` rule:

```
a:hover,a:active {
   text-decoration:none !important;
   color:grey !important;
}
```